# Poisson Distribution flaws in materials

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose the number of flaws in a certain type of material can be modeled as a Poisson random variable. If flaws appear on average once in every $150$ square meters, what is the probability of finding at most one flaw in $225$ square meters? State your answer to three decimal places.

---

If $X$ is distributed as a Poisson

$\Pr[X=x]= e^{-\lambda}  \lambda^{x}/x!$

$E(X)=1.5$

$f(x)=1.5^x e^{-1.5}/x!$

$\Pr(x=0)=e^{-1.5} 1.5^0/0!= 0,223$

$\Pr(X<1) = 1-\Pr(X = 0) = 1-0,223=0,777$

Is my procedure correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mean and Poisson distribution formula are correct but "at most one flaw" is same as $P(X \le 1)$ and not $P(X<1)$.

Also, $P(X<1) = P(X=0) $ ; $P(X\ge 1) = 1 - P(X<1) = 1- P(X=0)$

Comment: Thank you for your help